# Efficient way to fetch the total number of records in SQL server during Paging

Tags: sql, sql-server

When querying a table in sql server, im trying to fetch only the current page of records. However  I need the total number of records that would be returned for the particular query to calculate the number of pages. How to do this efficiently without writing another query to count the records.

```
 WITH allentities 
         AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY se.entityid ASC) AS 
                    rowid 
                    ,empid
                    ,lastname 
                    ,firstname
                     ,d.depname 

             FROM   emp e join dep d on e.depid=d.depid) 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   allentities 
    WHERE  rowid >= @pageid 
           AND rowid <= @pageid + 20
```

Comment: ...but the good news is, YOU can fix that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a second `ROW_NUMBER()` sorting `DESC` rather than `ASC`, you can calculate the total number of records by adding the two rowcounts together and subtracting one. Any row in the rsult set will have the correct total number of rows:

```
 WITH allentities 
         AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY se.entityid ASC) AS 
                    rowid 
                    ,empid
                    ,lastname 
                    ,firstname
                    ,d.depname 
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY se.entityid DESC) AS rowIdNeg
             FROM   emp e join dep d on e.depid=d.depid) 
    SELECT * 
            ,rowid + rowIdNeg - 1 as totalRecords
    FROM   allentities 
    WHERE  rowid >= @pageid 
           AND rowid <= @pageid + 20
```

Comment: this is awesome. Is this advantageous in terms of performance compared to my earlier query?

Comment: @Sundararajan S - there will be some additional cost for the calculation of the second `ROW_NUMBER`, but how great this is will largely depend on the arrangement your data and indexes.

Comment: For me, it's not giving the correct `totalRecords`. Should the first record have the correct total number of records?

Comment: What I have concluded is that the `se.entityid` has to be a unique value column in these two statements: `ORDER BY se.entityid ASC` and `ORDER BY se.entityid DESC`

Comment: @AdilMalik: Yes, the sort key (can be multiple columns) has to be unique. But that is already required for paging to work. You can force it by putting a primary key at the very end to break ties.

Answer (score 0):

If your application allows it, you can try to install and use search index to perform such queries. Search indexes have functionality to work with paging.

You can use for example http://lucene.apache.org/solr/. It can be configured to index Sql server db.

Comment: No. I want to do this with just sql server and sql query