# How to get result count while paginating the SQL Server query

Tags: sql, pagination, sql-server-2008-r2, rowcount

For displaying the total page number count I need also to retrieve total number of results at the below query. How can I do that ?

Thank you

```
select 
    AvgLevel, TotalCount, PokemonId, Type1, Speed, MonsterTotalStats 
from 
   (select 
       row_number() over (order by tblPokedex.PokemonId asc) rowNumber,
       AvgLevel, TotalCount, tblPokedex.PokemonId, 
       Type1, tblPokedex.Speed, MonsterTotalStats
    from 
       tblPokemonStats, tblAvailablePokemons, tblPokedex 
    left join 
       tblUsersPokemons on tblPokedex.PokemonId = tblUsersPokemons.PokemonId  
    where 
       tblPokemonStats.PokemonId = tblPokedex.PokemonId 
       and tblPokedex.Class = 'emissary' 
    group by 
       tblPokedex.PokemonId, tblPokedex.Type1, tblPokedex.Speed, 
       tblPokemonStats.AvgLevel, tblPokemonStats.TotalCount, MonsterTotalStats 
   ) result 
where 
    result.rowNumber > 0 and result.rowNumber < 101
```

Comment: thanks for editing @marc_s looks better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add column `Count(*) over()`:

```
..... 
select row_number() 
over (order by tblPokedex.PokemonId asc) rowNumber,
AvgLevel,
Count(*) over() as TotalCount,
.......
```

see example

```
select 
AvgLevel,TotalCount,PokemonId,Type1,Speed,MonsterTotalStats, TOTALRECORDCOUNT
from (
select row_number() 
over (order by tblPokedex.PokemonId asc) rowNumber,AvgLevel,TotalCount,tblPokedex.PokemonId,Type1,tblPokedex.Speed,MonsterTotalStats,
count(*) over() as TOTALRECORDCOUNT
from tblPokemonStats,tblAvailablePokemons,tblPokedex left join tblUsersPokemons on tblPokedex.PokemonId=tblUsersPokemons.PokemonId  
where tblPokemonStats.PokemonId=tblPokedex.PokemonId and tblPokedex.Class='emissary' 
group by tblPokedex.PokemonId,tblPokedex.Type1,tblPokedex.Speed,tblPokemonStats.AvgLevel,tblPokemonStats.TotalCount,MonsterTotalStats 
)  
result where result.rowNumber>0 and result.rowNumber<101
```

Comment: TotalCount is a parameter that exists on another table that shows how many monsters catched by players.

Comment: Ok call it "TotalRecordCount" so total count of records will be in each record you get from this query.

Comment: oh my bad. i saw it wrong. but it displays fetched row count which is 100 while there are total 527 records. so not working as intended.

Comment: You should use it in the inner query as in my example then it outputs ALL rows count in inner query before your WHERE in the outer query.

Comment: thanks working great. but your way or this way is better ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007803/efficient-way-to-fetch-the-total-number-of-records-in-sql-server-during-paging

Comment: ok i compared and the other one works pretty better in terms of IO read count. but thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

You coud use :

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

check it out [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx).

Comment: how do i add it to the query ?

Comment: it's a separate query, just use it below your query

Comment: i checked and it display the row count retrieved. so it displays 100 not the total number of possible results. Total number is 527 for example.

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve the total of?

Comment: Total available records. I am paginating between records. Like retrieve between 1-100 or 100-200. There is a total number of records which is for example for this query 527. So i also want to obtain that number in this query.

Comment: I think this is somewhat vague. Records of what? In relation to what? Please edit your question and clarify. You could also use `SELECT COUNT(*)`